# escaping single quotes inside a sh -c call on Mac terminal

Tags: shell, awk, sed, sh, xargs

I'm trying to pipe a series of manipulations into an xargs call that I can use to swap the first value with the second using the sed command (sed is optional if there's a better way).

Basically I'm grabbing method signature in camel case and appending a prefix while trying to retain camel case.

So it should take...

> originalMethodSignature

and replace it with...

> givenOriginalMethodSignature

Because I'm using a series of pipes to find and modify the text, I was hoping to use multiple params with xargs, but it seems that most of the questions involving that use `sh -c` which would be fine but in order for the sed command to be interactive on a Mac terminal I need to use single quotes inside the shell calls' single quotes.

Something like this, where the double quotes preserve the functionality of the single quotes in the sed command...

`echo "somePrecondition SomePrecondition" | xargs -L1 sh -c 'find ~/Documents/BDD/Definitions/ -type f -name "Given$1.swift" -exec sed -i "''" "'"s/ $0/ given$1/g"'" {} +'`

assuming there's a file called "~/Documents/BDD/Definitions/GivenSomePrecondition.swift" with below code...

```
protocol GivenSomePrecondition { }

extension GivenSomePrecondition {
    func somePrecondition() {
        print("empty")
    }
}
```

The first awk is going through a list of swift protocols that start with the Given keyword (e.g. GivenSomePrecondition), then they strip it down to "somePrecondition SomePrecondition" before hitting the final pipe. **My intent is that the final xargs call can replace $0 with given$1 interactively (overwriting the file).**

The original command in context...

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^Given/) print $0;}' ~/Documents/Sell/SellUITests/BDDLite/Definitions/HasStepDefinitions.swift \
  | tr -d "\t" \
  | tr -d " " \
  | tr -d "," \
  | sort -u \
  | xargs -I string sh -c 'str=$(echo string); echo ${str#"Given"}' \
  | awk '{ print tolower(substr($1,1,1)) substr($1, 2)" "$1 }' \
  | xargs -L1 sh -c '
      find ~/Documents/Sell/SellUITests/BDDLite/Definitions/ \
        -type f \
        -name "Given$1.swift" \
        -exec sed -i '' "'"s/ $0/ given$1/g"'" {} +'
```

Comment: What's your outer shell? (Do you _have_ an outer shell at all?)

Comment: Also, how locked down to `sh` are you? This problem goes away in its entirety if you can use bash or another shell with exported function support. (You don't even really need exported functions; `declare -f` or another command that prints the declaration of a defined function is enough to let you easily sidestep this problem).

Comment: Also, it would make it a lot easier to answer if you provided your inner code formatted for readability, split out from how/where it's wrapped.

Comment: It's going inside a sh script but Mac has zsh and bash support, so as long as I'm calling them specifically that would be fine

Comment: @CharlesDuffy tried to clean it up a little to help

Comment: I'm trying to clean it up at the same time, so we're stomping on each others' edits right now :(

Comment: BTW, note that `xargs -I anything sh -c '...anything...'` has major security risks and should basically always be avoided. Consider what happens when `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` gets substituted in place of `anything`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I here you on the security risk, but I'm just going to use this to modify the codebase once and then throw it away

Comment: BTW -- when you use `$0` and `$1` in the inner `sh` -- is that meant to refer to the arguments to your outer script, or the arguments `xargs` is passing to it?

Comment: $0 == "somePrecondition" and $1 == "SomePrecondition" from the simpler example.

Comment: Could I ask for a [mre]? Your current code can't be run by people who don't have a `HasStepDefinitions.swift` file, so I can't test my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `xargs` or `sh -c`, and taking them out reduces the amount of work involved.

```
echo "somePrecondition SomePrecondition" |
  while read -r source replace; do
    find ~/Documents/BDD/Definitions/ -type f -name "Given${replace}.swift" -print0 |
      while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
        sed -i '' -e "s/ ${source}/ given${replace}/g" "$filename"
      done
  done
```

---

However, to *answer* your questions as opposed to sidestepping it, you can write *functions* that use any kind of quotes you want, and export them into your subshell, either with `export -f yourFunction` in a parent process or by putting `"$(declare -f yourFunction)"` inside the string passed after `bash -c` (assuming that `bash` is the same shell used in the parent process *defining* those functions).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

replaceOne() {
  local source replace
  source=$1; shift || return
  replace=$1; shift || return
  sed -i '' -e "s/ $1/ given$2/g" "$@"
}

# substitute replaceOne into a new copy of bash, no matter what kind of quotes it has
bash -c "$(declare -f replaceOne)"'; replaceOne "$@"'
```

Comment: First off, thanks for taking the time on this. I've added an example file so you could test the command, as requested. I'm trying to test the first part from the command line but having some problems. Trying to adjust but getting "sed: 1: "/Users/jlingo/Documents ...": invalid command code j" Let me see if I can use your second option inside the script so I can approve the question.

Comment: Also my script starts with #!/bin/sh ... would I need to convert it to #!/bin/bash in order to use that local source format?

Comment: You need to use `#!/bin/bash` for `local` to be reliably available (some copies of `sh` support it, some don't), and for `declare -f` to be reliably available, and for `export -f` to be reliably available. Also for `read -d ''`

Comment: Should "replace=$1" be "replace=$2" ? Sorry I'm a little confused by the syntax

Comment: `shift` changes `$2` to `$1`, `$3` to `$2`, etc. So `replace=$1` is deliberate. That way `"$@"` expands only to `$3` and onward, because we ran `shift` twice before it.

Comment: btw, just to be clear, I'm _very_ suspicious as to the correctness of the `sed` syntax in use. I didn't change it because I assume you tested it to work on your platform, but... well, it looks suspicious to me.

Comment: The Mac version of sed is weird. The only way I could get it to overwrite was with ```sed -i '' 's/ $1/ given$1/g' {} +``` which I did get to work inside the pipe but it was before I realized I would need an uppercase first letter on the replacement value. This forced me to pass two arguments which is creating my issue. I'm trying the approach you outline calling a function, but a lot of that doesn't make sense to me and the capital "I" argument doesn't play well with my sed. In my other functions I set a global variable first, so not as familiar with passing in the args like that.

Comment: Yes, `sed -i '' "s/ $1/ given$1/g"` is what I would have _expected_ to be correct on a system (like MacOS) with BSD rather than GNU extensions. I only used the `-I` mess because it's what your original code had.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think autocorrect capitalized the -i and I missed it. Also had the single quotes before for some reason

Comment: BTW, if you know your shell is bash, and you have an adequately new version (not the ancient 3.2 version that Apple ships, but a modern 4.x or 5.x release), it has built-in support for capitalizing the first character in a string, so you don't need to pass two separate arguments to your function in the first place.

Comment: This has to work on Mac without upgrading

Comment: Okay that update seems to work better, but now getting ```sed: 1: "s/ theAppIsRunningWithP ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern``` The output from the previous awk command in the pipe comes out with string, space, string and then a new line for each result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238808/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-mercutio).